# How to add shortcut to Xfce (ubuntustudio)?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I went to

```
Settings => Setting Manager => Window Manager => Shortcuts
```

I can modify exist keyboard shortcuts, however, there's no Add option. I googled only found out that there's + (Add) button on Shortcut tab. Is there something wrong with my Xfce? or how could i add a shortcut, say open File manager, to Xfce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution myself:

```
Settings => Settings Manager => Keyboard => Applicatin Shortcuts => Add
```

I hope this might be useful to new Xfce users as well.