# How to add shortcuts for cycle windows to xfwm4?

Tags: linux, config, linux-mint, xfce

I want to add a shortcuts whose effect is the same as **`Alt+Tab`** to ***toggle between windows***. In other words, I want **`Alt+Tab`** and **`Super+l`** to have the same function.
Note: system is **Linux mint 14**

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028186/how-to-add-shortcut-to-xfce-ubuntustudio) in stackoverflow, but I can't find a command to do what I want.
I also found [this document](http://www.informatica.co.cr/linux-desktops/research/2001/xfce-3.8.1/adv-wm-bindings.html) to custom keyboard, but I have no idea how to do.

And I found the file *~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml* will be change when I modify shortcuts in the windows manager panel

When I tried to add two items to *xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml*

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;l" type="string" value="cycle_windows_key"/>
<property name="&lt;Alt&gt;Tab" type="string" value="cycle_windows_key"/>
```

It still didn't work even after reboot system, and the only change is shortcuts are shown in the windows manager panel.(For example: cycle_windows_key shortcuts show as **`Alt+Tab`**, but work as **`Super+l`**)

If anyone can solve it or give any suggestions, I will be very thankful :)

Comment: This might help - https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11422
They recommend the script, but it's only for toggling between different keys to use for `cycle_windows_key` action. As it seems xfce doesn't support different key combinations for this action. When I tried just adding another key combination using the technique they proposed, the old one stopped working.